# Problems with CoreLocation

Tags: swift, core-location

For some reason I cannot seem to get the users location. I bought the iOS 9 CookBook and coped their code exactly

Here is the ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
  let m = CLLocationManager()
  m.delegate = self
  m.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
  return m
}()

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager,
  didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    //TODO: now you have access to the location. do your work
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager,
  didFailWithError error: NSError) {
  //TODO: handle the error
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager,
  didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

  if case .AuthorizedWhenInUse = status{
    manager.requestLocation()
  } else {
    //TODO: we didn't get access, handle this
    print("No Access Granted")
  }

}

@IBAction func requestLocation() {

  locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

}

}
```

The output in the console is:

> No Access Granted

Any ideas what is going on? I have tested this on both the simulator and the device

Edit: I have added a button to the storyboard and licked that to the IBAction accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key to your plist? - The value should be a string describing why you want to use the users location.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Required to provide information about your location.</string>
```

If its all working correctly the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method should return an array of locations, you can print these out like so...

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    for loc in locations {
        print(loc)
    }
}
```

If you want to continually monitor the location you can call `manager.startUpdatingLocation()` instead of `manager.requestLocation()`

Comment: Oh thank you. That part was in a separate paragraph in the book. I will accept the nswer in 6 mins when it lets me :)

Comment: No problem, have fun with those `CLLocations`!

Comment: I don't suppose you would know, using the code above how I would print the Users location? The book section stops with the above code so a little stuck :/

Comment: In the didFailWithError function I added a print to say error. I added the code above and changed the requestLocation() to the startUploadingLocation() - When I press the button, It prints outs 'error' twice.

Comment: Instead of printing "error" as a string, print out the error variable and it should tell you whats wrong. `print(error)`

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know that. I am quite noobie. This now gives me: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

Comment: figured it out. It is because I have not set a location of the simulator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103947/discussion-between-wezly-and-jamesg).